# 2012, VW Jetta, stalls intermittently, restart after about 20 minutes. No code

Tags: vw, stall, jetta, code

My daughters 2012 VW Jetta stalls intermittently while driving. We've had it towed several times, and by the time it reaches the house it starts up again with no problem.  Other times when it hasn't been towed, it started back up with in a few minutes to an hour, and acts like nothings wrong.  It is also leaving no code.
After it stalls, during the time it won't start, the starter seems to be turning over fine.  The battery is recently replaced, and it's been checked even while stalled.  We've also tried jumping it while its in the stalled state but that doesn't seem to help.
The VW mechanic has had it a few times, and changed the crankshaft speed sensor/position sensor based on the symptoms.  But they haven't been able to replicate the problem.

I'm still paying on it, so would like to get it fixed.

Is there something else I should try; fuel pump, fuel pump relay, ignition switch?

Has anyone else dealt with a similar issue?

Comment: It could be anything, the repair shop needs to replicate the issue before they can diagnose it properly.

Comment: When it stalls, you can still crank it? I mean, you turn the key and ... *what*? It just won't start or it doesn't even turn over? Also, is this a diesel or which engine/transmission is in the car? How many miles (KMs) are on the vehicle?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 It has over 100,000 miles.  When you turn the key, it turn over, it just doesn't start.  It will start on the first try though, if you leave it sitting for a few minutes, or an hour tops.

Answer (score 1):

The next time it stalls and doesn't start, spray some starting fluid into the throttle body. If it fires up, you know you have a fuel delivery problem. If it doesn't fire, you probably have an ignition problem. This will help you determine which path to take to find the right repair.